# Implementing ImageIndex property editor in my FMX component

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-11-alexandria

I am designing a FireMonkey Component with TImageList and TImageIndex published properties. I can easily select a TImageList from the dropdown of the ImageList property, and the ImageIndex property seems to know that it should pick an image (it shows an icon next to the number), but there's no images in the dropdown for this property (only for -1), and the icon for the (manually entered) ImageIndex value (0) is shown as a "no icon" image (the same as for -1 in the dropdown):
[image: ImageIndex Property]

From the source (FMXReg.pas) it seems like I should call a line like this in my Register procedure:

```
RegisterPropertyEditor(TypeInfo(TImageIndex), MyControl, '', TImageIndexProperty);
```

but I can't find TImageIndexProperty anywhere.

The component works - it selects the proper image from the ImageList as defined by the ImageIndex property, even if I can't use the drop-down box (ie. if I enter the ID number manually).

How do I implement a proper ImageIndex property editor for my FireMonkey control? How do I tell it to look up the Images in the ImageList property?

(and yes: there are images in the ImageList, which I have verified by attaching the same ImageList to a standard TButton, and here the ImageIndex dropdown works without problems).

Comment: TImageIndexProperty is the part, that you should create yourself.

Comment: @Torbins: It's obviously already there in the IDE (since it's referenced in the source, and other ImageIndex properties work), so how do I "activate" it for my property / where is the source code for it?

Comment: Obviously, there is no source for that. Maybe it is a bug, because they have a lot of sources in $(BDS)\source\Property Editors but not this one. You can create a bug report about this.

Comment: Also there is a dclfmxstd280.bpl that has a unit called FmxImageListEditors. Probably you can add this bpl to your dependencies, and add this unit to your uses section.